# What symbol indicates a reference to another page?

Tags: typography, symbols

Historically, or in current common usage, are there any typography symbols which have the meaning "see page" or "refer to page", which can be placed near the page number?

Comment: A bit more context would help. Do you mean something to slot into paragraph text for a case like this: "As we discussed earlier (pp. 43-45), there are..."?

Comment: I often need this in various places, so answers related to various contexts would be helpful, however, currently this is used at the end of an encyclopedia-like article, indicating a related topic. Currently I have something like, "This text is at the end of the article about bears. See also, "Koalas" on p. 15." This way is too verbose though.

Comment: Technically, your problem is verbosity. There is not a symbol for "see also koalas." The page reference is `p.` which is about as short and symbolic as one can hope for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such page references are most commonly contained in parentheses, as @user568458 alluded to in the comments. This can change with the context. Here are two examples from my camera manual:

> In Auto Exposure mode, exposure is also locked in this case (page 54).

and

> With a moving subject, the camera ... as long as the shutter release button is kept lightly pressed (Focus Tracking, page 68).

This is used to reference a specific function (Auto Exposure Mode) or the parent topic (Focus Tracking) related to what you were just talking about. For something with a broader scope, such as the bear text, you would typically see that italicized at the end (or beginning) of the text.

> This text is at the end of the article about bears.
>   *See also, Koalas (p. 15)*